# How to list every accounts information and sum in sql without using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi everyone I'm having problems answering this question...

For every account list the number of events, the sum of deposits, the sum of withdrawals, and the sum of deposits and withdrawals. I'm having problems with the logic behind this. 
I keep thinking to myself that this requires a loop, but I know that wouldn't be correct... Does anyone know a way to go about this?

```
Database/Table structure: 
Account (accountNo, ownerNo, balance)
Owner (ownerNo, firstName, lastName)
Event (id, accountNo, event, amount, eventDate)
```

Code I've attempted:

```
SELECT COUNT(event) AS 'Account 1 number of events'
FROM Event
WHERE accountNo = 1
```

and then from there keep listing accounts- but for reusability that doesn't work for every account and its not efficient.

Comment: What is the structure of your tables and the nature of the data? This can be done in pure SQL however we can't offer any help with such little information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  account.accountNo,
  count(1) as number_of_events,
  sum(case when event.amount > 0 then event.amount else 0 end) as deposits,
  sum(case when event.amount < 0 then event.amount else 0 end) as withdrawals,
  sum(event.amount) as sum_deposits_withdrawals
from
  account
inner join
  event on
  event.accountNo = account.accountNo
group by
  account.accountNo
```